# PHP: array_ functions - short circuit?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to short circuit array_* functions in PHP? For example, array_reduce?

Comment: Like break out of the internal loop? I don't think so.

Comment: short circuit? can you expand??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use `array_reduce()` but implement an explicit loop and `break` from it when appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not inherently. Note the docs for `array_walk()` in particular:

> array_walk() is not affected by the internal array pointer of array.
>   array_walk() will walk through the entire array regardless of pointer
>   position.

Given that, you can kinda fake it by throwing an exception at the point you want to abort, then catch and ignore it:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

try {
    array_walk($array, function($value) {
        echo "$value\n";
        if ($value == 5) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Yields:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```